# Creating Categories using database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, categories

Hi I want to create Categories listed which are saved in my database so when user upload his images and he select the category it saves the data in database in Cat column 
Now I want to show category in PHP like this

```
Categories           Total
Animals               (4)
Celebrations          (2)
Locations And Travel  (11)
Object or still life  (1)
Transportation        (9)
```

Here is my PHP I am succeeded to show Categories names but not total category in each category

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","user");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"Select Cat from save_data Group By Cat ")
    or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Categories</th>

<th>Total</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['Cat'] . "</td>";



  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";



mysqli_close($con);



?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the table cell:

```
<td colspan="2"></td>
```

This way it extends over another cell.

Also I notice you are mixing mysqli and mysql:

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

Try to use mysqli as objects and `\Exceptions` instead of errors. It's worth learning about :-)

**Update:**

I did not understand your question at first. Please provide your schema so we can see your table structure.

Usually you would have **2 tables**, one with categories and one with data and join them with a `GROUP BY` (if an item can be in several categories, you would have a third table like `category_has_item`!):

```
SELECT c.category AS cat,
       COUNT(i.items) AS num
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN items i
  ON c.category_id = i.category_id
GROUP BY c.category
```

Use `LEFT JOIN` to display empty categories and `JOIN` (without `LEFT`) to avoid empty categories.

Change your table echo:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['cat'] . "</td><td>(" . $row['num'] . ")</td>";
```

**Update:**

If you only have 1 table, I strongly suggest you to read about `database normalization`.

Update your query:

```
Select Cat,COUNT(Data) AS num from save_data Group By Cat
```

Replace `Data` by your data column

and your echo line:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['Cat'] . "</td><td>(" . $row['num'] . ")</td>";
```

Comment: No I have one one table with name save_data and all of the data save in it and categories in Cat column of save_data @Dan

Comment: You really should get deeper in contact with the basics of SQL and PHP. I have updated the answer for you!

Comment: Amazing bro You are Awesome Love u :) @Dan

Answer (score 0):

try to change your sql query like this

```
SELECT count(*) AS total_count FROM (SELECT Cat FROM save_data GROUP BY Cat HAVING COUNT(Cat) > 1) AS t
```